# Is it good practice to keep SQL statements in properties file? - Java/Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I'm new in designing the application structure and recently I got a task to develop an application in Spring-boot. I'm also using Spring JDBC for database connection.

While working on DAO layer, I stumbled upon a thought that, where should I keep my SQL statements? First thing came to my mind was properties file. But later when I searched on web, I saw in most of the examples the SQL statements were in the method itself.

So, I just wanted to know what will be a good approach for this? As far as the application design is concerned.

- SQL in Properties file
- SQL in method body

Comment: I prefer stored procedures instead of SQL statements

Comment: I'm considering stores procedures as one of the worst anti-patterns not to follow. You'll remove yourself from the possibility to rather easily move you application to a different database and debugging sometimes can be a nightmare. All the benefits which might have been there 15 years ago are more or less not valid anymore and the drawbacks are bigger than the benefits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at [spring-data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/), it will save you a lot of the boilerplate code. You can specify custom SQL statements for your repositories (when they are necessary) in annotations.

See more details [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) and about custom SQL [here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-three-custom-queries-with-query-methods/) using the `@Query` annotation.

IMO, I think it's better to co-locate the SQL with the code where it is actually used as is done in this case.

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on the amount of SQLs your project has. If you have a dozen simple (i.e. CRUD) queries, it won't hurt to place the inside your code.

If you have many complex queries and some queries are included in others, some SQL bits are reused, etc., you should look towards using some library for managing your DB access. Property files are not meant to store queries, really (although, it's better that having your SQLs across a myriad classes!).

You can use either **Spring Data** if you employ JPA; even if you don't you will be able to place your SQL queries in a method annotation and Spring will autogenerate a method body for you at runtime.

Or, if your project is SQL heavy, take a look at **MyBatis**. It's great for projects with large and complex queries. It will generate method bodies for your DAOs and will allow you to place SQLs in `.xml` configuration files or, again, in method annotations.